# Mock a new object creation with constructor parameters in jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I need help mocking `new TableName(params).save()` used to create a new Dynamoose object in Jest. I have code that mocks `TableName.query(hashkey).eq(myhashkey).exec()` and similar queries. But I have trouble handling the `new` constructor with parameters. Can someone guide on how this is done in Jest?

Thank you so much for your time!

```
//Code that I want to mock
const tableName =await new TableName({
   hashkey,
   rangekey,
   ...moreItems,
}).save();

//Mock Object but this mocks TableName.save() rather than TableName(...).save(). mockModel creates a dictionary object to access the operations on the table and works for query/scan/get etc.
const saveFn = mockModel(
  'dummyTableName',
  'save',
  jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(exampleTableRecord))
);

//Mock assertion fails
expect(saveFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { TableName } from './TableName';

export async function main() {
  const hashkey = 'hashkey';
  const rangekey = 'rangekey';
  const moreItems = {};
  const tableName = await new TableName({
    hashkey,
    rangekey,
    ...moreItems
  }).save();
}
```

`TableName.ts`:

```js
export class TableName {
  constructor(opts) {}
  async save() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';
import { TableName } from './TableName';

jest.mock('./TableName.ts', () => {
  const mTableName = {
    save: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  };
  return { TableName: jest.fn(() => mTableName) };
});

const tableName = new TableName({ hashKey: '123', rangekey: '321' });

describe('main', () => {
  test('should ', async () => {
    await main();
    expect(tableName.save).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/55767756/index.spec.ts (10.88s)
  main
    ✓ should  (6ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.114s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/55767756